# Trying to get the ID from a link with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i'm actually trying to get the ID from some links I have in a nav. When I click in one of them, some text dissapear with CSS (display: none) and the text you wanted to check... appears...
The problem is, when I click the link, Alert doesn't appear, I receive no values.

HTML of the NAV

```
<nav id="options" class="work-nav">
      <ul id="filters" class="option-set">
           <li><a id="obras_link" class="selected">Obras expuestas</a></li>
           <li><a id="exposiciones_link">Exposiciones</a></li>
           <li><a id="bibliografia_link">Bibliografía</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#filters li a").click(function() {
    var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentID);
    /*if(currentID = "")
            $("obras_link").addClass("selected");
            $("exposiciones_link").removeClass("selected");
            $("bibliografia_link").removeClass("selected");

            $("#obras_expuestas").css("display", "block");
            $("#exposiciones").css("display", "none");
            $("#bibliografia").css("display", "none");
        break;

        case "exposiciones_link":
            $("obras_link").removeClass("selected");
            $("exposiciones_link").addClass("selected");
            $("bibliografia_link").removeClass("selected");

            $("#obras_expuestas").css("display", "none");
            $("#exposiciones").css("display", "block");
            $("#bibliografia").css("display", "none");
        break;

        case "bibliografia_link":
            $("obras_link").removeClass("selected");
            $("exposiciones_link").removeClass("selected");
            $("bibliografia_link").addClass("selected");

            $("#obras_expuestas").css("display", "none");
            $("#exposiciones").css("display", "none");
            $("#bibliografia").css("display", "block");
        break;
    }*/
});
```

});

It doesn't even appear errors in console. I have implemented JQuery library and the script in the HTML... so... I think ID.click values are wrong... any idea?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/89rxoxgr/. Do you get any errors in your console? BTW I recommend using `.hide()`  and `.show()` instead of `.css("display", "none")` and `.css("display", "block");`

Comment: if you're going to switch based off of the ID, why not just make the original jquery key off of that? `$('#obras_link').click(function() { /*case 1 here */ });`

Comment: I dont have any error. It's completely strange...

Comment: I wanted so simplify it

Comment: are those ids duplicated somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Why switch display for the items on/off by id?  Why not simply class the items and on click hide all items of the class and then show the one that is clicked?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not turn items on-off based on the class instead of having all that id-specific logic?

HTML:

```
<nav class="work_nav">
      <ul class="option_set">
           <li><a class="option selected">Obras expuestas</a></li>
           <li><a class="option">Exposiciones</a></li>
           <li><a class="option">Bibliografía</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Note: I changed classes to `work_nav` and `option_set` as `-` should not be used in id's or class names.

Javascript:

```
$('.option').click(function(){
    $selectedLink = $(this);
    $optionsInSet = $selectedLink.closest('option_set').find('.option');
    // turn off display of all options
    $optionsInSet.removeClass('selected').css('display', 'none');
    // turn on display of selected option
    $selectedLink.addClass('selected').css('display', 'block');
});
```

I don't fully understand why you need to both add/remove class and change CSS display property (I would think you could just assign that property to the class), so there may be more room for simplification.

This approach is much more flexible, as you could assign this behavior any set of DOM elements where `.option` elements are nested within some `.option_set` container. It need not be limited to ul/li/a structure.  You might also consider putting click event handling on enclosing `li` around `a` elements using this approach.

With this approach you could define any number of such option sets on your page, without having to worry about id's at all.  You could just have to make sure that all `.options` are descendants of the containing `.option_set` that defines the option groupings.

Now I don't really follow how one would be able to click on a deselected option since you have display set to none, but again I don't understand you full CSS that you have in play. Maybe you intent is to only let someone select an option once and then not be able to make any changes, which would be OK with this approach.

Comment: I don't have many idea about programming, so thanks for your help, it's really more simply... but it doesn't still work... http://gyazo.com/bd5c51a88eda4c02cbdaceaf70c9e66b "Projects" is the JS file where I put the code you wrote

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case?  Can you build a fiddle?

Comment: MMMM I have just change the order of the scripts... and it worked... ok, thanks dude xd